# How to display the required information inside the mark when clicks mark from KML on Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, kml

I'm getting the KML data from the Open Charge Map.

In general, when imports KML in google map, all the marks create in the map.

If I click a mark, the Mark doesn't show as like website.

I want to add the right style to mark.

The code for the importing XML is the following:

```
InputStream inputStream = kml_data
KmlLayer layer = new KmlLayer(map, inputStream, context);
layer.addLayerToMap();
```

What should I add here more?

I want to implement this mark in android app.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrErg.png)

Comment: Does your KML actually contain the balloon content that you want?  Does it work in Earth?  Can you provide a sample of the KML so we can try to debug?

Comment: Yes, The sample KML data is the following.